# How to prevent an iframe from opening new tabs?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to embed a Behance page into my website via iframe, but when the page is loaded, Behance opens 3 new tabs asking to sign in looks pretty awful:

[image: looks pretty awful]

Can I disallow this functionality? It doesn't even ask me, just opens these tabs. Some browsers that I tested block popups by default, but maybe I can set it manually to block them every time everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `iframe` element has a 'sandbox' attribute, which allows you to restrict the behavior of the `iframe`.

Checkout the detail: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox), see the part of `allow-popups`.